# Is pthread_cond_t an object or what?

Tags: c++, pthreads, conditional-statements

I am using a map as follows:

Keys ---> Task ID

Values ---> `pthread_cond_t` objects

When a certain task is done, I wake up all `pthreads` associated with it using the matching `pthread_cond_t` element.

My question is simple - what is `pthread_cond_t`? Is it an object? Because if I remove it,  the map invokes its constructor which is not good for me. If its not - can I just return

```
pthread_cond_t cond = *(_flushCond->operator [](task_id)); //map of conditions
_flushCond->operator [](task_id) = NULL;
return cond;
```

What I am trying to do is to free the object in map for later use (I reuse IDs) and return the `pthread_cond_t` object that was there.

Comment: pthread is a C API, so there's not going to be a constructor or anything. You should be able to pass it around freely.

Comment: But does it have any pointers, or anything other then primitive types?

Comment: It's an opaque type, so your code shouldn't care what's inside.

Comment: it's a struct. dont rely on having anything specific, it's opaque on purpose

Comment: Well I just need to know if the assignment I used is legal, I guess it is

Answer (score 4):

As others have commented it is an opaque type (or handle if you will) to an implementation defined type. In some implementations it might be a pointer to the actual condition variable structure, be the structure itself, of just a pointer to some implementation internal data structure. The POSIX standard makes no guarantee nor commitment about that, and there is only a certain set of operations that you are allowed to do with an "object" of that type. In that respect it is very similar to other types of Pthreads, like pthread_mutex_t or pthread_t.

You cannot safely or at least portably use pthread_cond_t as a value in an STL map. The reason is, that a requirement for values is to be copy constructable and assingable. While technically that is doable for pthread_cond_t, it is not [legal to do so](http://books.google.de/books?id=_xvnuFzo7q0C&pg=PA74&lpg=PA74&dq=pthread_cond_t+copying&source=bl&ots=Kn0U_SZ9Zc&sig=vTT58VZQwHxMfssp8F_tMZhWn30&hl=en&sa=X&ei=a3GpT4bfDYSN4gSCm6nBCg&ved=0CFgQ6AEwBA).

You should store a pthread_cond_t* (pointer) instead, like you would do with other types that are not "copyable".